# guile macro indentation in emacs

Tags: emacs, macros, scheme, indentation, guile

Is there something like `(declare (indent defun))` for guile so indentation of user-defined macros works like `define`s?

For example, if I write the following macro,

```
(define-syntax my-when
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((my-when condition exp ...)
     (if condition
         (begin exp ...)))))
```

Then, I get indentation that looks like,

```
(my-when #t
         (write "hi"))
```

But would prefer the following

```
(my-when #t
  (write "hi"))
```

In elisp, I could get the desired indentation via

```
(defmacro my-when (condition &rest body)
  (declare (indent defun))
  `(if ,condition
       ,@body))

(my-when t
  (message "hi"))
```

Version/mode notes: emacs 26, `scheme-mode` w/ `geiser`, `geiser-impl--implementation` = `guile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an indent hint for the symbol:

```
(put 'my-when 'scheme-indent-function 1)
```

This is more or less what `(declare (indent 1))` does in `defmacro`.

---

`lisp-mode` uses `lisp-indent-line`, which looks for the `lisp-indent-function` property on the symbol.  The built-in `scheme-mode` uses `lisp-indent-function`, so you would think that it would work just like in `lisp-mode`.  However the property name needs to match the mode name.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Indenting-Macros.html#Indenting-Macros for the values of the property.

Comment: In your init.el